# Tracking sign_up event as a Goal in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I wanted to create a Sign up goal in Google Analytics. Adding an event for signup is simple enough:

gtag('event', 'sign_up', { method: 'Direct' });

This successfully created events
[image]

However when I try to configure the goal as such:
[image]

Nothing happens, the Goal conversion is not counted for the events shown above.

I am trying to follow instructions from here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events

However I found very little documentation on tracking events as goals.

How do I configure a goal based on the standard engagement events in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set only Action equal to `sign_up` without value in Category.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. The "Use the Event value as the Goal Value for the conversion" is the problem. Because my event is not sending a value, GA assumes it has zero value and zero value goals are not counted as a conversion.

I fixed this by choosing No for the option and entering 2.5 as the value. Now anyone sending the event counts as a conversion worth $2.5.